# Libgdx InputProcessor pointer

Tags: java, input, touch, libgdx, multi-touch

I'm trying to **know which finger has being released**.
I have already read this tutorial http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputPolling

**This is my code using InputProcessor Interface** :

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
   debug_pointer = pointer;
}

public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
   debug_pointer = pointer;
}
```

When I press 1 finger : debug_pointer = **0**;

When I press another finger : debug_pointer = **1**;

(it's ok for now)

But if release the 1st **OR** the 2nd finger : debug_pointer = **0**;

I was excepting that debug_pointer would be : **1** if I was releasing the 2nd finger

I don't know with this returned number if it is the 1st or the 2nd finger who has being released

**How can I know which finger is released ?**

Comment: Your expectation seems correct to me.  I'm pretty sure I rely on the behavior you are expecting in my apps.  I think your problem may be elsewhere?  Can you show more code?  (If you track `pointer` in the `touchDragged` callback does that at least keep track correctly?)

Comment: touchDragged always show the last pointer. If the last pointer is released it shows the previous one, else it always show the last pointer.

Comment: Imagine that I'm trying to make a Ice Hockey on phone, I want to assign a finger to a sprite, and another finger to another sprite for a 2nd player, I would like to achieve this with InputProcessors

Comment: You get the position, you can check that with the last position, right? I'll try it out and get back to you later... (ping me if I don't)